# Git: bitbucket branch is not being pushed

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push, git-clone

I am asked to push some stuff in a branch of Bitbucket. There are 5 branches there:

- `master`
- `important1/B1`
- `important1/B2`
- `important2/B1`
- `important2/B2`

I am asked to push my stuff in `important2/B2`. When I clone the repository using the url `https://******@bitbucket.org/important/important.git` though, only `important1/B1` and `important1/B2` are being cloned on my hard disk, but other two directories are not being cloned.

Then I tried using some checkout command and I was able to clone only `important2/B2`, and then I tried to push that and it said everything pushed not to commit anymore. But I check bitbucket and my files are not in there.

What are the exact commands I have to write to clone my branch and then push it again? I am running out of time; that's why I had to ask here. By the way, I am new user of Git and Bitbucket also.

Comment: For one you can create a real user name instead of letters that just happen to be on the home row.  Second, what's the output of `git branch -a`?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but here is one way:

```
git clone https://******@bitbucket.org/important/important.git # if you already have a clone, just run git pull to get things up to date
git checkout -b important2/B2 --track origin/important2/B2 # will create a branch importan2/B2 locally and track the remote important2/B2 on origin (https://******@bitbucket.org/important/important.git)
# edit files
git status # check which files have been edited
git commit -m "COMIT_MESSAGE" -a # alternatively use git add per file before commit and no -a
git push origin important2/B2 # push your changes up to remote
```

If the last command fails, that is because changes were made on the remote during the time that you last pulled them in. You can remedy this by running `git pull --rebase` then push again, assuming no conflicts.